# Android app icon background colour different when run on real device

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created an app icon with a blue background colour but when I run the app on a real device the background colour has changed. It works fine on an emulator.

The preview for `ic_laucherer.png` shows this:

[image]

But on my phone it shows as:

[image]

Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem was in my manifest file. I had the following line:

`android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"`

which I changed to:

`android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

Answer (score 0):

Went through the same issue so I can help you.

Follow below steps :

1. Go to File > New > Image Asset.
2. Now in window look at the Source Asset
3. Select the Asset Type : Image
4. Now in path browse your app icon and select next and then finish.

Basically it will create all type of app icons.

Comment: I've tried this a couple of times but it still gives me the same issue